# Selenium/Appium explicit wait visibilityOf condtion is not throwing TimeoutException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Just want to understand when will below code throw any exception if or break out.

Currently it is keep on waiting for the element to be visible. But I thought it will throw TimeOutException in 10 seconds as it is been passed

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
try {
    webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    logIt(e);
}
```

Or Is this a design for visibilityOf method? Wait indefinitely until element is present/visible? Then what is the use of timeout in the WebDriverWait constructor?

I am little confused here though I am working on selenium for long time.

Comment: It should timeout after 10s. Do you have implicit wait on somewhere? That can cause weird timeout issues when you mix implicit and explicit wait (see the docs). I would write a simple test where you do nothing but this... remove the test from your framework, etc. and see how it behaves. My guess is that you've got something in your framework somewhere that is interfering with this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You may be correct. There might be loop hole in our framework.